# Is node.js ready for replacing server tasks?

Tags: java, javascript, node.js

I am watching node.js and its apps for a year now and I would love to replace bigger parts of my good old Java code with node.js.

The problem I noticed with node.js is that

- it looks like a chaos, from version to version things don't work anymore
- bad documentation, really bad
- no idea what libraries have been ported or will be ported any time soon
- multi core managment, does it ?
- uses 100% of the CPU power regardless of what it actually does (ie : pauses in loops). Thats not green and this is important to us.

Regarding security concerns I would put it behind a reverse proxy and only my old and real Java server would be able to use it.

update : funny this question gets closed because its not constructive. how can the question be constructive when I don't have any glue? Thats why also I am aksing here ! You moderators here really suck sometimes.

However, would you rather suggest to wait before moving to node ? Or do you think its time to move over ?

I'm writing loads of Java server side code and I would start building my own base framework and then port piece by piece!?

Comment: Pauses in loops?  Why would you do that?  This is a problem in your application code, not in Node.  Node itself definitely does not use 100% CPU all the time.

Comment: There are many other great asynch options today. `vert.x` is a big promise, there's also Netty. Maybe you should check them out instead. node.js is single-threaded, BTW, because JavaScript is.

Comment: "I would love to replace bigger parts of my good old Java code with node.js"......Why?

Comment: [Really bad documentation](http://nodemanual.org/latest/)?

Comment: sorry about the docs. things seem improved now.  And about vert.x : that looks really promising, thank you !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even if the questions gets closed:

- Actually, it works pretty stable and backwards compatible so far
- Are you for real ? --> http://nodejs.org/api/
- Again: http://www.nodejs.org
- Node didn't scale with CPU or core numbers, you should let the OS scale node processes by just launching multiple instances
- That is just wrong.

Even if *Node* still is "young" in comparison to other "server-side considered languages", it already found its place in a lot of spots. It can deal easily with huge amounts of users, it's an excellent *web-socket* server counterpart, its lightning fast when it comes to dispatching network traffic to a lot active connections and its ECMAscript, the most sweet sugar language ever made (the last statement is personal opinion).

There are probably hundreds of valid use cases for Node.js, obviously there is no specific task were it is a "must use", but thats the same rule for any language most likely. Its fun, its fast, dig into it.

Comment: thanks about for the update. good to know that things changed.

Comment: Please follow the suggestion, "you should consider to leave a comment when downvoting"

Comment: You may have been downvoted because you answered a question you knew to be inappropriate. Users are more likely to ask inappropriate questions if they've seen them get answers, so answering them could be seen as encouraging poor behaviour. (I'm not suggesting that mc007 knowingly asked a "not constructive" question, but still, it sets an example for others.)

Comment: well, I knew what I was doing and I actually answered it in a more rhetorical way I hope. Just too many false assumptions and accusations. However, all I asked for was showing a little class and leave a statement. Anyway, nevermind :)